# Wordpress easiest install?

Tags: wordpress, web-development, website-design

What is the easiest way to download/install wordpress? I'm having problems getting it. Also does wordpress cost anything to use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

WordPress is free open source software that can be [downloaded here](http://wordpress.org/download/).  There [installation guide is here](http://codex.wordpress.org/Installing_WordPress).